# ASP.NET Performance issue in System.Web.Hosting namespace

Tags: asp.net, performance, redgate, red-gate-ants

I'm using RedGate ANTS to troubleshoot performance problems in an ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms app. When clicking in very small pages sometimes, it takes up to 15 seconds to load. These are pages without any data - just a handful of controls.

ANTS Profiler is telling me that the hotspot methods (Time with children > 5 seconds) are all within System.Web.Hosting, for example:

- ExecuteFunctionDelegate
- PipelineRunTime

But the "own time" of these is under 0.001 second each. There's nothing else that's a hotspot. So what can be "beneath" these methods that could be causing this issue?

Comment: I think I've cracked it - this thread is probably the app waiting for ANTS itself, since I have it set to the most accurate and intrusive profiling mode (line by line).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to switch from CPU time to wall-clock time, if you want to check for methods that take a long time IRL. There is probably an asynchronous wait (WaitForSingleObject) that is not taken into account when you are using CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, but using wall-to-clock it still shows the longest hotspot being some mystery thread, i.e. not the application code. Many of the hotspots are in System.Web.Hosting... why would they be taking a long time (as in > 5 secs)?

Comment: I can't answer because I do not know about the internal workings of that namespace. But if it's ANTS, you can try a faster profiling method. You won't get line-level in the MS namespaces anyway.